# Why won't my concurrent asp.net requests from the same client execute concurrently?

Tags: asp.net, iis, concurrency

IIS 7.5, .Net 4.6

From the browser network diagnostics tab I can see that the requests are stacking rather than executing concurrently. 
This can be seen with the static content requests (e.g., stylesheets, images, javascript) which are waiting for the dynamic request to complete before they complete. 
I also devised a test where a javascript timer is used to make requests for static content on a regular interval. (Let's call it "http-ping".  If I have a long running main request, these http-ping requests back up.

With perfmon, I have determined the following counters increment as my http-ping requests stack up:
Requests Current;
Pipeline instance count;

while these counters remain at zero:
requests in native queue;
requests queued;
requests in application queue;

I have also inspected the app state with debug.  Only one thread, corresponding to the main request, is active in application code. Other threads show stack location as "".

Comment: Sessions can cause that. Delete the cookie from Fiddler and execute requests to test this.

Comment: If I delete the session cookie, my main request will fail.  It requires a session.

Comment: Then test with a resource. You said that resources are also affected.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @usr,  the session is the problem.  Indeed, use of session state inhibits concurrent actions on the same session, per [this msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx).  In my case I might be able to use

```
[SessionState(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
```

to alleviate the problem.